# Using Guzzle to get data - Strange Error

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

This is my code

```
public function getAllCountries() {
    $countries = array();
    $response = $this->client->get($this->geoCountryAPIURL, [
        'query' => ['username' => $this->username]
    ]);
    $body = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
    if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
        if (array_key_exists('geonames', $body)) {
            $dataRespone = $body->geonames;
            // error or status response
            foreach ($dataRespone as $country)
            {
                $countries[] = array(
                    'geonameId' => $country->geonameId,
                    'countryName' => $country->countryName
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return $countries;
}
```

In my PHP Error Logs, I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in on line 35

Line 35 is

```
if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
```

Comment: `var_dump($respons);` will help you.

Comment: I'm getting the countries. I get this array from stdClass error. Any way I can do this via guzzle

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode()` returns an object, unless you pass `true` as the second parameter.

Even if it says that the error is on line 35, it can be on the next line. Error messages aren't always 100% correct, but usually gives you a good starting point.

So, the line it actually complaining about is probably this:

```
if (array_key_exists('geonames', $body)) {
```

..since `$body` is an object.

Change that row to:

```
if (property_exists($body, 'geonames)) {
```

...and it should work.

Are you sure that this: `foreach ($dataRespone as $country)` is correct? I don't know what the response looks like, but: `foreach ($dataRespone->geonames as $country)` seems more likely. As far as I know, you can't loop a `StdClass`-object.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Gk8130fU
Entire code. and http://imgur.com/a/Q6v8d is the rsponse of this code

Comment: What error are you getting now? The same or something different?

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in LocationHelper.php on line 43

Comment: Did you try the last part of my answer? Change the foreach?

Comment: Line 43 =   $countries[] = array(
                        'geonameId' => $country->geonameId,
                        'countryName' => $country->countryName
                    );

Comment: Please var_dump `$body` after your `json_decode()` and show us what it contains.

Comment: and if you var_dump $dataRespone right after `$dataRespone = $body->geonames;`?

Comment: It says array right after $dataResponse = $body->geonames
http://imgur.com/a/KrYO2

Comment: Then I'm sorry. I don't see the error, if the code you posted is the actual code you're running.

Comment: Can you run it? Please?

Comment: It's same as my username - kirobo

Comment: I took your code from pastebin and tried, it works as expected.... no errors. http://prntscr.com/cbo3v7